# How to write a meta tag in a .aspx-page?

Tags: asp.net, meta-tags

I have the following code:

```
<%@ page title="בחירת מועמדי הליכוד" language="C#"
masterpagefile="~/Site.master" autoeventwireup="true" %> <asp:Content
ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content> <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"
ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> <center> <div class="endMsg"> תודה
רבה על השתתפותך ! </div> </center> </asp:Content>
```

I want to add the meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60; url=http://your.new/url/here" />
```

How do I write code which is interpreted as that meta-tag?

Edit:
Based on a comment, I wrote this code:

```
public partial class Thanks : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _refresh_In_Seconds = 5;
        HtmlMeta metaKey = new HtmlMeta();
        metaKey.Name = "Refresh";
        metaKey.Content = _refresh_In_Seconds + "; url=Default.aspx";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaKey);  
    }


}
```

The redirect doesn't work. Can anyone explain why?

Edit 2:

This is another solution to the problem:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10; URL=Default.aspx">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
             HtmlMeta metaKey = new HtmlMeta();
             meta.Name = "Refresh";
             meta.Content = _refresh_In_Seconds + "; url=whatEver.aspx"; 
             Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaKey);
```

Comment: Thanks!

I added this:<code>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int _refresh_In_Seconds = 5;
        HtmlMeta metaKey = new HtmlMeta();
        metaKey.Name = "Refresh";
        metaKey.Content = _refresh_In_Seconds + "; url=Default.aspx";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaKey);  
    }
</code>
It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HttpEquiv property of HtmlMeta, so instead of:

```
metaKey.Name = "Refresh";
```

put:

```
metaKey.HttpEquiv = "Refresh";
```